# the server request method prints GET even though the form method is POST

Tags: php, post

i wrote this code below and when i submit the form the $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] prints GET instead of POST even though the form method = "POST"

```
<?php
    include "init.php";
    include $temp . "navbar.php";
    echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=='POST'){
        echo $_POST["name"];
    }
?>
<input type="hidden" value="admin" class="title">
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
<?php
    include $temp . "foot.php";
?>
```

Comment: It is correct since you have used `GET` method to access the page

Comment: It should change to `POST` when you _submit_ the form? Of course it will be `GET` when you first access the page

Comment: Even though I suspect Areg is right, how did you access the page?

Comment: If you _submit_ then you make a `POST` request

Answer (score -1):

You can simply check if `$_POST['name']` *is set*:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    // ...
}
```

And since you are posting to the same page you don't need to include the `action` attribute in your form.

```html
<?php
    include "init.php";
    include $temp . "navbar.php";
    if(isset($_POST['name']) {
        echo $_POST['name'];
    }
?>
<input type="hidden" value="admin" class="title">
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
<?php
    include $temp . "foot.php";
?>
```